# A-frame gltf textures seem inverted

Tags: aframe, gltf

It's my first time importing a gltf that I exported from Blender and the textures in A-frame are inverted and black and white but retain a speckle of the ofiriginal color. It looks good on the gltf viewer of Don McCurdy. Very weird! I'm using latest A-frame version.

Any ideas what could be causing this?[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there a sample model or blender project you could share?  Or screenshots of the Blender material settings?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your faces normals are pointing out and that you export materials when exporting from Blender.